# Formatting months based on the years present in previous row python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the below, is there any way to format months till December as 'DEC-2017', based on the value in index 0 and months after December as 'JAN-2018'? I'm using Python 2.7.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-18','','','','','','','','','','',''], ['APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JULY', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC', 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR']])
```

output should look like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2017-18','','','','','','','','','','',''], ['APR-2017', 'MAY-2017', 'JUN-2017', 'JULY-2017', 'AUG-2017', 'SEP-2017', 'OCT-2017', 'NOV-2017', 'DEC-2017', 'JAN-2018', 'FEB-2018', 'MAR-2018']])
```

sorry I'm new so don't know how to paste a dataframe here and thus using codes.

Comment: I wasn't able to work it out. Sorry I'm new to formatting or pasting the dataframe here. The output should look like APR-2017, MAY-2017, JUN-2017, JULY-2017, AUG-2017, SEP-2017, OCT-2017, NOV-2017, DEC-2017, JAN-2018, FEB- 2018, MAR-2018

Comment: If you have any follow up questions, It is always best to open a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `cumsum` + `iloc`

```
df.iloc[1] += '-' + (df.iloc[1].eq('JAN').cumsum() + 2017).astype(str)
```

```
df
         0         1         2          3         4         5         6   \
0   2017-18                                                                
1  APR-2017  MAY-2017  JUN-2017  JULY-2017  AUG-2017  SEP-2017  OCT-2017   

         7         8         9         10        11  
0                                                    
1  NOV-2017  DEC-2017  JAN-2018  FEB-2018  MAR-2018
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. But, is there any way to do it automatically. The next time it's 2018-19 in the index 0, I don't want to manually replace '2017' and '2018' in "cumsum + where".

Comment: @greenarrow all better now.

Comment: when I try this: `df2.iloc[1, 1:] += '-' + pd.Series(np.where(df2.iloc[1,1:].eq('JAN').cumsum(), '2018', '2017'))`, it would replace the last column value i.e. 'TOTAL' as nan. See the dataframe 2 for better understanding.

Comment: Now it seemed to work: `df2.iloc[1, 1:-1] += '-' + (df2.iloc[1,1:-1].eq('JAN').cumsum() + 2017).astype(str)` using this for df2. Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. The only problem now would be if there's 2018-19 instead of 2017-18 in the first row.